# Настройка проекта с Databinding

Tags: android-data-binding

Grandl project

```
   buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha04'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()



}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Grandle module

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
dataBinding {
    enabled =true
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rus.pr663"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }



}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
compile 'com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha04'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Ошибка при синхронизации:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha04
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:library:3.2.0-alpha04
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:adapters:3.2.0-alpha04
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Что не так с настройками?

Answer (score 0):

Измените в `dependencies {}` . зависимости как

```
compile 'com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha04'
```

на

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha04'
```

так же измените в файле gradle-wrapper.properties   вот на это

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Ни первое ни второе не помогло.

Comment: В первом случае вообще убрал строчку за ненадобностью.

Comment: Во-втором случае красно красно при синхронизации даже не знаю что копировать. Все остановилось на Configure Builde. Ох уж эти Grandle'ы . Уже делаю сложные проекты но так в этих настройках и не разбираюсь

Answer (score 0):

При запуске проекта

```
 Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.2.0-alpha04.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/Rus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.pom
file:/C:/Users/Rus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.jar
file:/C:/Users/Rus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.pom
file:/C:/Users/Rus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.jar
file:/C:/Users/Rus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.pom
file:/C:/Users/Rus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.2.0-alpha04/baseLibrary-3.2.0-alpha04.jar
Required by:
   project :app
```